# Dynamic Log4j2 Logfile-Path

Tags: java, xml, logging

I want to set a directory in Log4j2.xml dynamic.

**The Log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
    <Configuration status="WARN">
        <Appenders>
            <Console name="Console">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            </Console>

            <RollingFile name="MyFile" fileName="${sys:logDirectory}/app.log"
                         filePattern="${sys:logDirectory}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <Pattern>%d %p %c [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
                </Policies>
                <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="2000"/>
            </RollingFile>

        </Appenders>

        <Loggers>
            <Root level="DEBUG">
                <appender-ref ref="Console" level="INFO"/>
                <appender-ref ref="MyFile" level="ERROR"/>
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

**Run:**

```
public static void main(final String[] args) 
{
    System.setProperty("log4j.logDirectory", "C:\\debug.log");
    org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext ctx =
            (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    ctx.reconfigure();
    log.error("TEST");
}
```

**The Output:**

> 2017-03-15 18:20:27,131 main ERROR
>   Unable to create file ${sys:logDirectory}/app.log java.io.IOException:
>   The syntax for the filename, directory name or drive name is wrong.
>   --- EDIT: the original error message in german was: ---
>   (Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch.)
>   ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it and I only found out that if I do this it works for me;
System.setProperty("logDirectory", "C:\debug.log");

So try to remove log4j. in your config statement.
System.setProperty("log4j.logDirectory", "C:\debug.log");